# Is the following an encryption algorithm? If so, is it reversible?

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption, encoding, hash

I came across the following method in a programming example. Is this really an encryption algorithm? Or is it more of a hex hashing/irreversible encoding algorithm? I see the use of bitwise shifts and bitwise ands which leads me to believe that the method has data loss and is an irreversible hex encoding algorithm.

```
 private string  Encrypt(string key, string message)
    {
        string result = "";
        var hexValues = "0123456789abcdef";
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
        {
            var a = (Int32)message[i];
            var b = (Int32)key[j] & 10;
            var encChar = a ^ b;
            if (++j == key.Length)
            {
                j = 0;
            }
            result += hexValues[(encChar >> 4) & 15];
            result += hexValues[encChar & 15];

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: what happens when you run the code and debug it..? why don't you do that and tell us what your expected outcome is ..

Comment: Debugging doesn't directly answer whether the result is reversible.

Comment: Bitwise XOR is fully reversible (just XOR anything with the same value/key twice). The bitwise AND is just used to select the high and low end nibble of the byte to perform hexadecimal encoding. Hex encoding of bytes is of course also fully reversible.

Comment: The AND on the key value just makes sure that only the 2nd and 4th least significant bits of each byte are encrypted with the corresponding key values (ouch).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At its heart, this algorithm is performing [XOR encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher), a weak and easily broken form of encryption.

```
var encChar = a ^ b;
```

The bit shifts are used to get a hex value corresponding to the "encrypted" character position.

```
result += hexValues[(encChar >> 4) & 15];
result += hexValues[encChar & 15];
```

The & mask is used to select a value to XOR the character at the given position against.  It is providing a "hidden" change to the key, a practice sometimes called *security through obscurity* (which does not add much to the actual security).

```
var b = (Int32)key[j] & 10;
```

Comment: Am I mistaken, or does `& 10` make sure that only two bits of each byte (0b0000_1010) are actually "encrypted" ?

Comment: Only two bits of the "key" digit are actually used, which reduces the key space and makes the algorithm all that much easier to hack.

Comment: This was very useful. I was not familiar with the bit shift algorithm to convert to/from hex to dec since most APIs have conversion methods built in (e.g., Convert.ToString(dec, 16)). That helped clarify what I was looking at.